# DCO Comment Attachment Plugin not working correctly in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Can someone assist me with sizing the DCO Comment Attachment plugin in Wordpress?  I have tried resizing the widget but that didn't work. Attached is a snapshot of the issue.  The 'At' in Attachment is showing up in the website textbox.  When I click in the name, email or website textbox the file explorer box opens.

[image]

I looked at the code and here is a snapshot of what I found.  I am not sure where the error is in the textarea.

[image]

Comment: It seems like a div was left open, but unable to tell for sure without reviewing the code. Are you doing any custom filtering for this form? I have also seen the DOM do funny things with an HTML ID used more than once on the same page. Check all of your form ID to make sure you don't have any duplicates.